# SQL Connection Won't Run During Transaction

Tags: c#, sql, .net, transactions, sqlconnection

I've got 2 scenarios both running the same code and one works 100% of the time while the other fails just as often.

I have 2 sql connections pointing to the same sql server locally while a transaction is going on. When I try to run a query against the second connection, it times out. While debugging, I can even go into SSMS and try to run a query and it will just sit there as well. The fact that it works in the other scenario is odd, but ultimately I'm trying to figure out why sql is locked up when I'm running the other sqlconnection.

Does anyone have any ideas on what could cause this or any debugging tools I could use? I'm not interested in using a transactionScope.

If I close the first connection beforehand, the second connection's query will run just fine.

Here is when the issue happens. At this point we have sqlconnection1 that has a transaction attached and running:

```
                    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
                    connection.Open();

                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("", connection);


                    command.CommandText = "a read command"
                    int  count = command.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: Can you attach connection to the same transaction as sqlConnection1? That should be fairly easy if you use transaction Scopes, but if your sql provider doesn't allow that..

Comment: No, I can't associate the transaction with multiple connections unfortunately. I was aware that the scope did this though, which is why I tried to use that before realizing it needed that service. I would if it was a personal project, but it is not feasible for me to require that service now.

Comment: And why using two connections then?

Comment: Solely because I could possibly be querying a different database. In this scenario it ends up being the same. Maybe that's what needs to happen. I can check if it is the same and use the same connection. I'll see if the problem exists when they are on different databases.

Comment: If they are different database there shouldn't be any locking. You need to worry if there could be different processes/threads quering the same database with that code though, even if you just use one connection.

Comment: I'll be sure to keep that in mind. I think the solution here would be to use the same connection if it ends up being the same database. Thank you for talking through this with me. If you want to make an answer with this, I'll give you the points.

Comment: I have added the use one connection thing in the first answer, as the bit of isolation level I think is important too.

Comment: Consider using one connection and one tran with multiple databases. That makes this issue go away. You can switch databases or use 3-part names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed, first thing is that if you don't need two connections you can just use one so everything runs in the same transaction.

If you need this set of SQL run in parallel with other processes or threads running similar queries, you may want to revisit the isolation and locking of your statements.

You are probably running the first transaction as Serializable isolation and doing updates on it. Consider using ReadCommited (or Snapshot ReadCommited). But that would depend on your actual work.

From SSMS, try running first

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READUNCOMMITTED
```

That should avoid the locks created by fist transaction, but this is just so you can see why its happening, is not a good idea to use that isolation level!

Comment: This allowed me to run queries in SSMS. I'm unfamiliar with this so let me do some research and I'll let you know if it solves my issue. Thank you for the information!

Comment: The easiest way you have to change the isolation level is to create a transaction scope, not sure why you want to avoid it.

Comment: It looks like I can still set the IsolationLevel of a basic SqlTransaction. I am avoiding the scope because I'm not running the Sql service that it needs (the name escapes me right now).

Comment: I set the isolation level for the transaction, confirmed that at the point of failure it still has the property set correctly, and it still locks up. It also still locks up in SSMS, but explicitly setting it in SSMS will allow me to query from there. EDIT: I set the isolation level to ReadUncommitted by the way.

Comment: Sure, it it just 1 transaction, but 2 sql connections. The transaction is attached to sqlconnection1 which does reads/writes. Partway through, I initialize sqlconnection2 and it does a read from a different database alltogether.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to think of how I can do that. It's many methods with plenty on non-sql related stuff going on. There are also plenty of commands that I am running using the sqlconnection1. It isn't until I try to use sqlconnection2 that things go wrong.

Comment: I would say that each connection is using different transactions, otherwise no locks should happenn

Comment: I have a meeting, so I will check in later. Thank you for your help.